# how to cite a review from the media online using bib.tex

Tags: bibtex, citing

How to cite a review from the media online using bib.tex?
i.e. Shiller (2017). " Economy" Sciences. Jul.21. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: a MWE would be helpful... help us help you, show us what you have so far, and what you want to get

Comment: I would suggest to switch over to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [`biber`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber). `biblatex` not only provides `@online` for the standard styles and [most addons](http://ctan.org/topic/biblatex). It also supports `url` and `urldate` for almost all entry types.